# Present/ Past tense between sentences with past tense?

Tags: tense, past-tense

> She overcame all of her difficulties and created her own destiny as a merchant all by herself.  That **is** not all. After making a large fortune,  she willingly donated almost all of her wealth to her starving neighbors. I really respect her way of life.

Here, if i use **was** instead of **is,** the focus of the thing verb indicates would be changed?

Comment: I wouldn't see any real difference between them. "That" refers to the previous statement either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) That is not all. [as I tell the story now]

That implies that there is more to the story you are telling.

2) That was not all. [that happened to the lady]

That implies that more happened in the story you are telling.

So, it depends on how you want to express yourself. Both are right.

[please note: created her own destiny as a merchant is a bit much. Perhaps shopkeeper is better. And "created a future for herself as a shop owner"/

Answer (score 0):

We use "that is" to give an example or a clarifying comment.

The word "that" is a dummy subject. It refers, in some way, to the current text or "What I am saying" (or similar) and so uses the present tense.

So could be understood as

> She overcame her difficulties all by herself... What I have said is not all I could say...